# Problems with python decorators returns

Tags: python, decorator

I'm having some problems with the decorators return.
I would like to create a decorator to calculate the function duration time, so I build this code to learn how to work with decorators.

When I use the decorator with the print method, it works, but the intention of this code is to return the message saying the function name and the duration time.

```
import time

def timer(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        init_time = time.time()
        res = function(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        Answer = str(f'The function {function.__name__} takes {end_time - init_time} seconds to be executed.')
        print(Answer)
        return res
    return wrapper

def timer2(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        init_time = time.time()
        function(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        Answer = str(f'The function {function.__name__} takes {end_time - init_time} seconds to be executed.')
        return Answer
    return wrapper

@timer
def calculator():
    soma_tot = 0
    for i in range(1,1000000):
        soma_tot += 1
    return soma_tot

@timer2
def my_name(Name):
    print(f'Hello, my name is {Name}')

calculator()
my_name('Leonardo')
```

So I got two problems:
1 - If the function return something, the decorators is not returning the function return;
2 - The decorators just print the answer, it's not returning it so I can reuse the answer.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the return values of your two functions, so it doesn't matter what the decorator returns - the value goes nowhere.

Comment: If I try to print the return, with that request:
```
print(timer(calculator()))
print(timer2(my_name('Leonardo')))
```

The response is:
<function timer.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000025D614E5040>
Hello, my name is Leonardo
<function timer2.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000025D614E5040>

And I still without the funcition duration time.

Comment: Just do `print(calculator())` - `timer` was already applied to the function via the `@timer` line just above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `timer2`:

```
def timer2(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        init_time = time.time()
        function(*args, **kwargs)  # Where does the result go?
        end_time = time.time()
        Answer = str(f'The function {function.__name__} takes {end_time - init_time} seconds to be executed.')
        return Answer  # You return an unrelated string
    return wrapper
```

Then,

```
calculator()  # What do you do with the return value?
my_name('Leonardo')
```

In fact, `timer2` should be exactly like `timer`. No need to create a new function.

When you use `calculator()`, check the return value and you'll see it works:

```
res = calculator()
print(res)
```

Comment: Changing the return without the str() function, and printing the decorated function insted of print the decorator worked.
Now I need to know how to return the function result and the decorator result.

Answer (score 0):

So guys, this is the code that I remake with your help, and now it's working.

```
import time

def timer(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        init_time = time.time()
        funcReturn = function(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        result_time = end_time - init_time
        if funcReturn == None:
            response={"FunctionName":function.__name__, "TimeSpent":"{:.5f}".format(result_time)}
            return response
        else:
            response={"FunctionReturn":funcReturn, "FunctionName":function.__name__, "TimeSpent":"{:.5f}".format(result_time)}
            return response
    return wrapper

@timer
def calculator():
    soma_tot = 0
    for i in range(1,1000000):
        soma_tot += 1
    return soma_tot

@timer
def my_name(Name):
    print(f'Hello, my name is {Name}')

print(calculator())
print(my_name('Leonardo'))
```

In this way, I'm getting the result of function (print or return) and getting the execution time of the function.

Thx all.